# What is the current state of knowledge regarding embryology (from an animal husbandry perspective) in Mars-g gravity?

Tags: mars, astrobiology

Before anyone comments - obviously, we don't have any experimental data. But do perhaps we have ISS or other data that can be extrapolated from?

What I'm asking specifically is, what do we currently know about the development of, for example, a fertilized chicken egg in Mars g? For the purposes of this question, assume that we've handled any radiation problems...

Comment: We have very little data on low-gravity situations. All our data is at 0 or 1 G. E.g. it's not clear that health problems are proportional to gravity.

Comment: There is some data at more than 1 G. Some generations of laboratory mice were raised in a centrifuge on earth under some G. There were some experiments with a centrifuge in a satellite, see page 19 of http://iaaweb.org/iaa/Scientific%20Activity/Study%20Groups/SG%20Commission%202/sg22/sg22finalreportr.pdf

Comment: I don't know how the centrifuge approach escaped me. So you could place an egg in a centrifuge on the ISS and simulate Mars g.

Comment: Not only eggs but also different small mammals, even for some generations. But such a rotating centrifuge would not be perfectly balanced and would disturb the microgravity environment of the ISS by vibrations.

Comment: Probably doesn't need to be perfectly balanced to get good data. And I would say that an experiment like this is the raison d'etre of the ISS.

Comment: But other experiments designed for microgravity may be disturbed by the vibrations caused by a badly balanced rotating centrifuge..

Comment: They can figure it out. There are going to be vibrations from equipment there no matter what they do.

Comment: The ISS was supposed to have a centrifuge module for just this sort of experiment. It's rotting in a parking lot in Japan now. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifuge_Accommodations_Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of experimental data for microgravity conditions.  But the only **Mars-gravity** [experiment](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5913308/) that I could find in the National Library of Medicine used an in vitro culture of plant cells.  That's as close as we've come to an animal embryo.  It found that

> altered gravity effects include a serious disturbance of cell proliferation and growth, which are cellular functions essential for normal plant development.

-- "Simulated microgravity, Mars gravity, and 2g hypergravity affect cell cycle regulation, ribosome biogenesis, and epigenetics in Arabidopsis cell cultures," by Kamal et al, *Scientific Reports* 2018:6424, https://dx.doi.org/10.1038%2Fs41598-018-24942-7.